# Javafx - Update progress indicator in UI from java class

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder, progress-indicator

The  following are the changes I made in fxml

Changes in the java file , here my code :

```
private ProgressIndicator pi;

void handlebuildButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

if ((entServer.isSelected()==true || compasServer.isSelected()==true)) {

            if(!fileList.isEmpty()){
                ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
                pi.setProgress(10);
}
}
```

The progress indicator is not updated when I run the application. I'm not sure how to sync the changes to UI. Assist me on this. Thanks in advance.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7xTS.png)

Comment: Missed fxml changes   
<ProgressIndicator fx:id="pi" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="280.0" progress="0.0" />

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

For example: if you set 0.1 - progress will be 10%, 0.2 - 20% and so on, **so when you set the progress => 1 you will always have "done".**

Here, this an example with a button, when you click the button, your progress indicator will be updated(one click + 10%):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    private ProgressIndicator pi;
    private double counter = 0;
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
        Button button = new Button("Press");

        TilePane root = new TilePane();

        // action event
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                counter += 0.1;
                pi.setProgress(counter);
            }
        };


        button.setOnAction(event);

        root.getChildren().add(button);
        root.getChildren().add(pi);

        // create a scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

        // set the scene
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // launch the application
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Just change this code for your case:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if ((entServer.isSelected()==true || compasServer.isSelected()==true)) {

                    if (!fileList.isEmpty()) {
                         counter += 0.1;
                         pi.setProgress(counter);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: I tried but it is not working. As in the attached snap the percentage is still set to 0.

Comment: The example of  the program with the button works, I've just check it.But if your program don't work, please **give more information and code examples.**

Comment: FXML-I have just added a progress indicator using scenebuilder.
Controller.java - I want to indicate the progressIndicator step by step (on completion of few tasks) . But it is not getting updated . I can't have a button and hit it everytime to increase to percentage. I want it to increase gradually after each step.

Comment: You need to put this code in thread, in example you have see that code for Event Handler in method void Start(Stage stage) that works like thread for JavaFX application.

Comment: At first provide your program code. Your piece of code provide a bit of information

Comment: Can I reach out to you through mail or any other mode? Im not allowed to paste my code completely due to some restrictions.

Comment: Just edit your answer(add all your program code) and it will be better or write to email tt186004@gmail.com

Comment: _Im not allowed to paste my code completely due to some restrictions._ that's no problem because you must provide a [mcve] anyway ;)